# when I start Desktop Rstudio every time, I get an error message as:rstudio error yaml.load readlin con errorlevel errorlevel

Tags: rstudio, desktop

after I login the Desktop Rstudio, the following message will appear:

```
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
and I try to reinstall R and Rstudio with the newest program,it still appear error again.
when I start R program ,it can work with no error. Only Rstudio, and I try to rename the directory"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop" in another name, Let it create when Rstudio launch,the error message again. 
And I can't knit some Rmd file working normal, it will appear following error:
Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  找不到对象'C_unserialize_from_yaml'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous>
停止执行
```

Who can help me to slove the problem.Thanks very much.

Comment: What version of RStudio and `yaml` are you using?

Comment: I'm having the same issue: ***Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) :  object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found***. Also, knitr does not work with the same error.

Comment: having same issue - happened after updating yaml to 2.1.15

Comment: Sounds like you have still got 2.1.14.  The `C_unserialize_from_yaml` object is new in 2.1.15.  Did you shut down R and restart?

Comment: I have installed n the package ‘yaml’ version 2.1.15

Comment: Istalling 2.1.14, as suggested by @alan_y below, fixed all issues. Knitr now works (I have R 3.4.2 and RStudio 1.1.383).

Answer (score 3):

I reverted to yaml R package version 2.1.14 and it fixed it for me.
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/yaml/

Use this R command to install the package from source (provided the working directory is set to where the R package is):
`install.packages("yaml_2.1.14.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

Comment: Did you try installing 2.1.15 from source?  I did, and it worked fine.  Binary installs for Windows aren't available yet.  Use `install.packages("yaml", type = "source")`.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.I have deleted the yaml package and reinstall it and recompile it again.after I do this, and restart again,It work normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
require(devtools)
install_version("yaml", version = "2.1.14", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

It resolved my issue