# RStudio installation - yaml error messages

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio

Having some issues helping a colleague at work install RStudio. She was getting the following error message whenever she opened up the programme and when trying to install new packages.

```
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
    object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...) : 
    object 'C_unserialize_from_yaml' not found
```

Seems to be the error that's being discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617532/when-i-start-desktop-rstudio-every-time-i-get-an-error-message-asrstudio-error). We've followed the steps in the answers and haven't had any luck.

Uninstalled the `yaml` package, reinstalled RStudio and got a different error message (not surprising given the package was no longer installed).

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
```

Then tried each of the answers in the link and ended up with the original error message again.

Beyond what I've googled in the past 15 minutes, I don't know anything about `yaml` or what it's supposed to do. Opening R rather than RStudio seems to work as it should.

R version is 3.4.3, RStudio is 1.1.423 for Windows and yaml version that was originally installed was 2.1.16. Not sure if it's relevant, but we are on work laptops that require us to install new programmes (and in the case of R, packages) into `C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\My Software`, but that seems to have been done correctly.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

James

Comment: You might get better support from the Rstudio support forums: https://community.rstudio.com/c/rstudio-ide

Comment: Thanks, will post the query over there as well